# Is the solutions to potential well correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

https://github.com/LaurentNevou/Q_Schrodinger1D_demo
The code can be obtained by

link：https://pan.baidu.com/s/1w6Rb3GY6WFjPY_XHYrPsYQ
code：2178

*Any copyright belong to the original author for this code, I put it here just for discussion.*

When I use the above code to slove energy states of a rectangle potential well (3.3eV, 1nm thick),
I found the solutions above the well are not continuous. In principle the scattering states should be continuous. So I am confused with the result.[image]

Comment: How are they not continuous?

Comment: You seem to be missing half of the bound states: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/pfbox.html

Comment: It is difficult to interpret your diagram as presented.  Could you give some explanation? The page at github is, as usual with github, opaque.

Comment: 1 To say not continuous I mean the energy value of scattering states seems not continuous. 2 Yes the solution should be Even-odd alternativly. So I guess the code I use is just for demon the isolated states by the potential well. Not accurate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's useful to be specific with words like "continuous": you should specify that you are talking about the spectrum of energy eigenvalues being continuous. Wave functions are always continuous everywhere. The first spatial derivative thereof can be discontinuous when the potential is infinite (which doesn't happen realistically, but is part of many exactly solvable models, including the infinite square well).
2. The issue mentioned by the question regarding the spectrum not being continuous presumably arises from the fact that the number of scattering states drawn is finite. That is simply a constraint imposed by the fact that clearly drawing the spatial dependence of a continuous spectrum in such a plot is next to impossible, so the authors settled for drawing a large number of them with small energy separations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think my problem should be caused by the code I use. I am trying another code.

Comment: A agree with your comment about the code.  You have to be careful to understand what your code does "at infinity".  Is it "very far away"?  Could be, but that's still not infinity, and you could still get a discrete spectrum.  One option commonly done in condensed matter physics is to apply "periodic boundary conditions"  where the values of the wave function and its slope at the left boundary is the same as at the right boundary.   (Doing physics on a torus.)  I'm pretty sure that if the code is doing that it will give you a discrete spectrum of scattering states.